# Problems with downloading apps

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have recently brought a Samsung Cooper and when i was trying to download an app from the market it keeps saying insufficient memory on device. My phone has a 16GB memory card and the internal memory i big enough for the app.

Does anyone have any ideas why its saying this please.

Thanks.

Comment: I've had this problem on my Vibrant the last couple days with big apps.  Maybe a Market bug?

Answer (score 1):

One of the more obvious things to attempt is to clear the Market data/cache.

Another thing to try is to backup all data on your SD card. Next - format it from within your Android device, then copy back all the data. Corrupted files on your SD card can also cause installation failures (even if you aren't installing to an SD card), or so I've heard.

Answer (score 0):

OKay, I had this problem a couple days ago. Here's the fix. On the market, look up an app called "MarketFix" It's a very small app, so it shouldn't cause any problems. I was able to download it when I couldn't download anything else. Download MarketFix, run it, and click its one button. I'm not sure exactly what it does, but it solved this problem on my phone.

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the insufficient memory error probably means RAM and not the storage space. If this is the case, I've found that its usually because most of my apps are installed on the phone memory and not on the SD card. Try moving your apps to the SD card from the phone memory. Keep in mind that doing so would prevent you from using that app's homescreen widgets.

Comment: It seems like you're kind of mixing terminology here. RAM is not where apps are installed, it's memory used by running processes. Moving apps to your SD card won't free up RAM, but it *will* free up storage space.

Comment: and the OP has already mentioned he has enough space.